CompletableFuture supplyAsync, thenApplyAsync, thenAcceptAsync working incorrect
I made Async CompletableFuture so that I would first make a payment and then sleep for 10 minutes. And this was repeated endlessly. But sleep once doesn't work anymore
public class PaymentWorker implements Callable<AutoPayResult> {
    private boolean isActive;
    private UUID workerId;

 @Override
    public AutoPayResultV2 call() {
  // toDo something pay method 
}

 public void stopWorker() {
        isActive = false;
    }

}



@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AutoPaymentServiceV2Impl implements AutoPaymentServiceV2 {
    private final List<PaymentWorkerV2> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    private volatile boolean isActive = false;

private void runProcess(PaymentWorker z) {
        log.info("Starting worker with id: {}", z.getWorkerId());

        CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(
                        z::call
                )
                .thenApplyAsync(s -> {
                            stopWorkerById(z);
                 
                            return s;
                        }
                )
                .thenAcceptAsync(d -> {
                            if (isActive) {
                                var pw = new PaymentWorker(
                                        isActive,
                                        UUID.randomUUID()
                                );
                                workers.add(pw);
                                sleepAfterFinishWorker(pw.getBranch());
                                runProcess(pw);
                            } else {
                                log.warn("Auto payment V2 is not active and will be stopped");
                            }
                        }
                );
    }


    private void stopWorkerById(PaymentWorkerV2 paymentWorkerV2) {
        log.info("Stop workerwith id: {}", paymentWorkerV2.getWorkerId());

        workers
                .stream()
                .filter(z -> z.getWorkerId().equals(paymentWorkerV2.getWorkerId()))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(w -> {
                            log.info("Worker found for removing");
                            if (w.isActive())
                                w.stopWorker();
                            workers.remove(w);
                        }
                );
    }

    private void sleepAfterFinishWorker(String branch) {
        var seconds = 1000 * 60;
        log.info("Sleep worker after finishing for: {} seconds", seconds);
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(seconds));
    }
}

The logic is this:
First it takes "worker" and then makes a payment using the call method. After completion, it removes this “worker” from the list so that it cannot be processed again. Then it sleeps for 60 seconds. Then it creates a new “worker” again and does the same thing again.
All processes should be asynchronous, creating a separate thread

Look at the documentation for LockSupport.parkNanos.  It does not do what you think it does.  If you want to sleep, use Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000) or TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds).

Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

Letting the missing thread safety aside, it’s not clear what you expect from this code. Whether these PaymentWorker objects are in the worker list, has no impact on the logic at all. Further, there is nothing in this code ever setting isActive to true.
